# pipとyumの違い ／ pipはPythonバージョンに応じて小数点毎に変動？

Tags: python

**Q1.yumでインストールしたbeautifulsoup4が、ソースからコンパイルしたPython3.6で認識できませんでした。どういう原因が考えられるでしょうか？**
・yumでインストールしたbeautifulsoupは、yumでインストールしたPythonでしか使用不可？
・yumでインストールしたbeautifulsoupのバージョン(4.1)が、Python3.6未対応？
・何かのパスがおかしい？
※最終的にはpip3.6でインストールし直したので正常動作しています

---

**Q2.yumは依存性を解決してくれるので極力利用した方が良い、という認識でいたのですが、Pythonには当てはまらない？**
・Pythonの依存性解決はpip？

---

**Q3.pip3.6は、Pythonバージョンに連動？**
・pip3.6コマンドだけ使用できるのですが、これはPythonバージョンに連動しているのでしょうか？
・pip3.6コマンドでインストールしたライブラリは、(パス等が自動的に設定され？)Python3.6で動作することが保証されている、ということでしょうか？
・ネットで「Python 3ではpipコマンドと同じ動作をするpip3コマンド」と書いてあったのですが、Python 3.X系なのになぜ使用できないのでしょうか？
・Python3.6は他と何か違う？？

```
$ pip
```

> -bash: pip: コマンドが見つかりません

```
$ pip3
```

> -bash: pip3: コマンドが見つかりません

```
$ pip3.6
```

> Usage:      pip  [options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ディストリビューション・バージョンがわかりませんが、yum ということですので、RHEL/CentOS/Fedora を想定して回答します。

> Q1.yumでインストールしたbeautifulsoup4が、ソースからコンパイルしたPython3.6で認識できませんでした。どういう原因が考えられるでしょうか？

yum で提供されている beautifulsoup4 が、違うバージョンの Python 用なのではないでしょうか。
例えば、EPEL で提供されている python-beautifulsoup4 をインストールすると、/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/ 以下に配置され、python-2.7 では利用できますが、python-3.6 では利用できないものと思われます。

> Q2.yumは依存性を解決してくれるので極力利用した方が良い、という認識でいたのですが、Pythonには当てはまらない？

yum の base, updates で提供されている python パッケージは、OS 標準の python-2.7 用に作成されていますが、すべての python パッケージが用意されているわけではありませんし、バージョンが古い場合があります。

また、SCL, EPEL, [IUS](https://ius.io/GettingStarted/) などのリポジトリを追加すれば、`python34`, `python36u` といった、別のバージョンをインストールできますが、これらのリポジトリからインストールできる python パッケージは、base, updates と同様に、リポジトリで提供されている python 用に作成されたものです。

したがって、python 本体を yum リポジトリからインストールし、かつ、そのバージョンに合った python パッケージが用意されているのであれば、yum でインストールすることができます。
そうでなければ、pip などで、yum とは別の方法でインストールする必要があります。

> Q3.pip3.6は、Pythonバージョンに連動？

pip3.6 でパッケージをインストールすると、python 3.6 用のものがインストールされます。
python 3.6 のライブラリディレクトリの下の site-packages/ にインストールされると思います。

pip3.6 は実行できて、pip3 が実行できないのは、そのようにインストールしたからとしかいえませんが、pip3 -> pip3.6 とシンボリックリンクを作成すればいいのではないでしょうか。